# Copy/paste table contents to another table?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to copy/paste table contents to another table without deleting destination table.

I've found out that If I copy range and special paste values only it will not delete the table, however if the source is a table it will delete destination table...

I've tried this:

```
dr.ClearContents
sr.Copy
dr.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

sr being source range and dr destination range.

Comment: Pretty sure that's possible, could you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Where exactly are you pasting into the table? (i.e. does `dr` represent the entire table, or the first row, first column of the table body)?

Comment: It's the whole table with headers and totals. sr and dr. Basically I just want to update values in a table at range dr from another file at range sr without breaking references to dr range. And like I said pasting from range will work but pasting from table won't which is pretty strange to me. Behaviour is the same with manual copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made a program to copy table body seperately from table field names.